# keeping line height vertically centered in div without a fixed height

Tags: percentage, css

I am working on a responsive website using a standard grid system so my divs cannot have a fixed height.  With that said, I have setup a fiddle file to *simulate* my problem. I have a min-height of 50px for cosmetic reasons on a desktop and set line height also to 50. so the text is centered vertically in the div. If you make the window more narrow, the line will eventually break of course. Is there a way to maintain keeping the content vertically centered after it breaks so it does look so bad?

here is some of the code:

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

here is the fiddle file: http://jsfiddle.net/HFAew/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't center verticaly in CSS BUT you has some workarounds for different situations. In your case I recommend use display: table; in a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/HFAew/1/

```
<div class="verticalCentered">
    <div class="box"> test content test content test content test content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.verticalCentered {
    display: table;
    height: 100px; /*variable*/
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    display: table-cell; /**/
    vertical-align: middle; /**/
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But remember it has problems sometimes. It is useful only in certain situations. Other ways: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually the issue didnt get solved. what I meant was that when the line breaks lets say into 3 lines (depending on how narrow) they are now spaced so far apart. I was hoping there was a way to keep the lines closer together and stay in vertical center area of the parent.  when the line breaks in your example, see how much space between lines.

Comment: Of course. Because you put line-height: 50px; It defines the height of a single line in a paragraph. Set it, for example, to **line-height: 1.5em;** : http://jsfiddle.net/HFAew/10/